# Restrict user to submit the form while processing the previous request

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a button "print" in my jsp page. When I click on the button, a child window is opened and pdf is genarted in the child window. Once user already clicked on print button and the request is processing, I need to disable the button and show a message. My form is submitting in javascript.

I have searched for disabling buttons, but no luck. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Get the button id and disable the button in javascript as 
    $(#btnid).attr("disabled", true);

If you are opening a new child window and have no control on the parent page to enable it then disable it for a particular amount of time and then enable it back
    setTimeout(function() { enableButton(#btnid) }, 1000);

```
var enableSubmit = function(btnid) {
   $(#btnid).removeAttr("disabled");
}
```